# second Do while loop not executing

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a code that searches through a record using do..while loop, after that i want to search the record again based on another IF condition but it would only execute the first do..while and jump over the second

I tried to comment out the first loop and the second was executed but it jumps over while and execute the first one if i remove the comments

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Dim code, prodname, QP1_combo, QP1_name, QP1_CAS, component_Type, CONTENT_Lower_limit, BEARBEITER As String
Dim CONTENT, Informationsquelle, Anzahl_Partner, Anhange, Kommentar, end_datum, datum_kunde, datum_dossier, compedium As Variant
Dim CONTENT_Upper_limit, Bearb_Start_Partner, Bearb_End_Partner, profile As Variant
Dim Date_of_entry, Bearb_Start_Datum, Bearb_End_Datum As Variant
Dim Checker As Integer
Dim Duplicate_Checker As Integer
Dim existing As Integer

Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_MASTER")


    Checker = 0
    Duplicate_Checker = 0
    existing = 0

    '*******************************************************
    'Verify that the essential fields have values.
    '*******************************************************
    If IsNull(Me.txt_code.Value) Then
        Checker = MsgBox("Product code cannot be empty", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Me.txt_code.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_prodname.Value) Then
        Checker = MsgBox("Please enter the product name", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Me.txt_prodname.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_QP1_combo.Value) Then
        Checker = MsgBox("Please select PURE QP1.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Me.txt_QP1_combo.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_component_Type.Value) Then
        Checker = MsgBox("Please select the component type.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Me.txt_component_Type.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txt_BEARBEITER.Value) Then
        Checker = MsgBox("Please fill the bearbeiter field.", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Me.txt_BEARBEITER.SetFocus
    End If

    '*******************************************************
    'Checking for duplicacies in the database.
    '*******************************************************
    code = Me.txt_code.Value
    QP1_combo = Me.txt_QP1_combo.Value

    If Checker = 0 Then

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            If rs("PRODUCT_CODE") = code And rs("PURE_QP1") = QP1_combo Then

                Duplicate_Checker = MsgBox("Record already in the database!", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate")

            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If

    '*******************************************************
    'This is the do while that is not working being executed
    '*******************************************************

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If rs("PRODUCT_CODE") = code Then

            existing = MsgBox("Product code was entered earlier", vbOKOnly, "Duplicate")

        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop


    If Checker = 0 And Duplicate_Checker = 0 Then
        Call read
        Call NewAddition
        MsgBox ("Record successfully saved")
    End If

End Sub

Sub NewAddition()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("T_MASTER")

    '*******************************************************
    'Updating the database.
    '*******************************************************

    rs.AddNew
    rs("PRODUCT_CODE") = code
    rs("PRODUCT_NAME") = prodname
    rs("PURE_QP1").Value = QP1_combo
    rs("PURE_NAME_QP1").Value = QP1_name
    rs("PURE_CAS_NR").Value = QP1_CAS
    rs("Component_Type").Value = component_Type
    rs("CONTENT").Value = CONTENT
    rs("CONTENT_lower limit").Value = CONTENT_Lower_limit
    rs("CONTENT_upper limit").Value = CONTENT_Upper_limit
    rs("Date_of_entry").Value = Date
    rs("BEARBEITER").Value = BEARBEITER
    rs("Bearb_Start_Datum").Value = Bearb_Start_Datum
    rs("Bearb_Start_Partner").Value = Bearb_Start_Partner
    rs("Bearb_End_Datum").Value = Bearb_End_Datum

    rs("Bearb_End_Partner").Value = Bearb_End_Partner
    rs("Anzahl_Partner").Value = Anzahl_Partner
    rs("Informationsquelle").Value = Informationsquelle
    rs("Anhänge").Value = Anhange
    rs("Kommentar").Value = Kommentar
    rs("Datum_Statement_Kunde").Value = datum_kunde
    rs("Datum_Statement_Dossier").Value = datum_dossier
    rs("Profile_Y_N").Value = profile
    rs("Compendium_Y_N").Value = compedium
    '   rs("Thema").Value = topic
    rs.Update


End Sub

'*******************************************************
' Reading the values.
'*******************************************************
Sub read()

    prodname = Me.txt_prodname.Value

    QP1_name = Me.txt_QP1_name.Value
    QP1_CAS = Me.txt_QP1_CAS.Value
    component_Type = Me.txt_component_Type.Value
    CONTENT = Me.txt_content.Value
    CONTENT_Lower_limit = Me.txt_CONTENT_Lower_limit.Value
    CONTENT_Upper_limit = Me.txt_CONTENT_upper_limit.Value
    'Date_of_entry = Me.txt_Date_of_entry.Value
    BEARBEITER = Me.txt_BEARBEITER.Value
    Bearb_Start_Datum = Me.txt_Bearb_Start_Datum.Value
    Bearb_Start_Partner = Me.txt_Bearb_Start_Partner.Value
    Bearb_End_Datum = Me.txt_Bearb_End_Datum.Value

    Bearb_End_Partner = Me.txt_Bearb_End_Partner.Value
    Anzahl_Partner = Me.txt_Anzahl_Partner.Value
    Informationsquelle = Me.txt_Informationsquelle.Value
    Anhange = Me.txt_Anhange.Value
    Kommentar = Me.txt_Kommentar.Value
    datum_kunde = Me.txt_datum_kunde.Value
    datum_dossier = Me.txt_datum_dossier.Value
    profile = Me.txt_profile.Value
    compedium = Me.txt_compedium.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `rs.MoveFirst` before you try to execute the `Do While ... Loop`.

Because the first loop leaves the recordset on the last entry, the 2nd loop never executes because the recordset is already on the last record.

For that matter, why waste time looping the recordset, when you can just query the recordset to test for duplicates and return a message based on the results?